# How do I get rid of grids when using plot() in R?

Tags: r, plot, vegan

So I'm using R to perform a DCA (detrended correspondence analysis) through Vegan package and everytime I plot my results I get a grid in the middle of the plot.

I want to get rid of it.

Here is my code:

```
dca <- decorana(dados)

plot(dca, type = "n", ann = FALSE, origin = TRUE)
        text(dca, display = "sites")
        points(dca, display = "species", pch = 21, col="red", bg = "red", cex=0.5)
        mtext(side = 3, text = "Análise de Correspondência Retificada (DCA)", font=2, 
              line = 2.5, cex=1.8, font.lab=6, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=1.5)
        mtext(side = 1, text = "Eixo I", font=2, line = 2.5, cex=1.5, 
              font.lab=6, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=2)
        mtext(side = 2, text = "Eixo II", font=2, line = 2.5, cex=1.5, 
              font.lab=6, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=2)
```

And here is the result:
[DCA plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/966Y0.png)

Do you see that grid line from x=0 and y=0? That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned frequently in the various documentation and tutorials in existence, if you don't like the default plots produced by `plot()` you are free to build your own from either the low level plotting functions supplied by R or the intermediate functions we provide in **vegan**.

The main complication here is that, for one reason or another, we can't not plot the origin lines with `type = "none"` in the `plot` method. But even that is solvable by plotting the scores yourself.

```
library("vegan")
data(dune)
dca <- decorana(dune)
spp <- scores(dca, 1:2, display = "species")
sit <- scores(dca, 1:2, display = "sites")
xlim <- range(spp[,1], sit[,1])
ylim <- range(spp[,2], sit[,2])
plot(spp, type = "n", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, asp = 1, ann = FALSE)
text(sit[,1], sit[,2], labels = rownames(sit))
points(spp, pch = 21, col = "red", bg = "red", cex = 0.5)
title(xlab = "DCA 1", ylab = "DCA 2")
```

Here's a side-by-side comparison of the default `plot.decorana` and what the above draws

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that dotted line is created by the plot function from looking at lines 66 and 67 of the [source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/15734725):

```
abline(h = 0, lty = 3)
abline(v = 0, lty = 3)
```

The only way to get rid of it is if you copy the function code and remove those two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Draw two white lines to cover them up, then draw your points on top.

```
abline(h=0, col="white")
abline(v=0, col="white")
```

Then draw a box to remove the gaps created in the border by the ablines

```
box()
```